# Sum of the value of node with only one child

Tags: java, sum, binary-search-tree

I was trying to sum the value of BST's nodes with exactly one child.
however, for some reason, it didn't going through.
For example, the input{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10} and the output of it should be 45. I only got 2.
and for {5, 2, 1, 7, 6, 8, 10}, i got 0. I'm in the BST tree. Could anyone explain it and fix my code?

```
public class Node {

        Integer value;
        Node parent;
        Node left;
        Node right;

        public Node(Integer value) {
            this.value = value;
            this.parent = null;
            this.left = null;
            this.right = null;
        }
    }   
public Integer oddNodeSum() {
        
        return oddNodeSum(root)  ; 
        
    }
    private Integer oddNodeSum(Node root) {
        // START YOUR CODE
        int index=0;
        if (root==null){
            return index+=0;
        }
        else {
            if (root.left!=null&&root.right==null){
                index += root.left.value;
                oddNodeSum(root.left);
            }
            if (root.left==null&&root.right!=null){
                index += root.right.value;
                oddNodeSum(root.right);
            }
            return index;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem on your code is you are traversing node only when the condition of adding node (with one child) are satisfying. instead of it, `you need to traverse all the child and you need to consider those node whose having only one child`.

i modified your code like following:

```
private int oddNodeSum(Node root) {
    int sum = 0;
    
    if(root == null) {
        return 0;
    }
    /* node with only one child */
    if((root.left == null && root.right != null) || (root.left != null && root.right == null)){
        sum += root.val;
    }
    /* traverse all node and add whose having only one child */
    sum += oddNodeSum(root.left);
    sum += oddNodeSum(root.right);
    
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's explained everything!

Answer (score 0):

Initialise the `index = 0` in `oddNodeSum()` function, before the `oddNodeSum(root)` is called and pass the index into the `oddNodeSum(root, index) and try to implement the logic over there. This will rectify your issue

Comment: sorry, i'm not followed. could you explain in another way？Sorry for the troubles.